# How to load jsp page as template in component in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular2-template

I want to load the external jsp page content as template in my component in angular 6 application.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-conrequest',
  templateUrl:'mydomain.com:port/utils/registerUser.jsp',
  styleUrls: ['./conrequest.component.css']
})
```

In the above code, I have mentioned the jsp page url, which I want to load as a template.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

First of all whichever external link you are using it should "return" something.
If there is no information in return it will always gives you an error.

Lets begin your answer...

Step 1- First you need to import HttpClient and Map

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Step 2- and your @Component decorator should look like this

```
   @Component({
          selector: 'my-template',
          template: `<div [innerHtml]="myTemplate">
                    </div> `})
```

Step 3- in your class you can import your external template like...

```
    export class TestComponent  {

  private myTemplate: any = '';
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    http.get('www.abc.com/index.html', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(data => this.myTemplate = data);
  }
}
```

Step 4 - Also import httpClient in RootModule

```
    imports: [
   ...
   ...
    HttpClientModule

  ],
```

That's it. Try with yours.

Thanks
Sunil Sain

Comment: I'm getting the below error. {ERROR in ./src/app/conrequest/conrequest.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ <div [innerHtml] = "crTemplate"></div> ' in 'C:\project_files\new_angular6
_workspace\impactangular\src\app\conrequest'
ERROR in ./src/app/conrequest/conrequest.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/map' in 'C:\project_files\new_angular6_workspace\impactangu
lar\src\app\conrequest' }

Comment: Acc. to your description 
1. Are you missing declaration of Component in root module
2. run this command "npm i --save rxjs-compat" to install rxjs for solving map operator problem